# Add a file from url to docker image is ends in different result when using volume

Tags: oracle, docker, jdbc, docker-compose, keycloak

I would like to use Keycloak latest version (14.0.0) Docker image with Oracle JDBC, and as far as I know `jboss/keycloak:14.0.0` image does not come with Oracle JDBC driver.

First, I added the driver to the proper directory as a volume in a docker-compose file.

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:14.0.0
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
      - 9443:8443
    networks:
      - bifrost
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
      - ./jdbc:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver
    depends_on:
      oracle-db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

I downloaded the file into `jdbc` directory and renamed the jar to `ojdbc.jar` as they recommend it in their description.

It worked well until I tried to push it to remote, which is gloriously rejected by the remote git host because the file size is too big. We cannot change this limit, so the best solution that I can find is to build the image since `ADD` command can get resource from the web and add to the image

So this is what I come up with:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:14.0.0

ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver/ojdbc.jar
```

and the `docker-sompose.yml`:

```
  keycloak:
    build:
      context: ./keycloak
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
      - 9443:8443
    networks:
      - bifrost
    environment:
      ...
    depends_on:
      oracle-db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

However, with this solution Keycloak could not start, it always fails with the following error

> 11:54:39,493 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database

So the Keycloak application behaves like there is no Oracle JDBC driver present, as soon as I add back the driver like previously as a volume, it works perfectly.

I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, what's the difference between the two scenarios?

According to my knowledge, there should no be any difference and should work just fine in both cases.

The jar in the `jdbc` dir is exactly the same as I add in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

> In the case where <src> is a remote file URL, the destination will have permissions of 600.

Test:

```
$ ls -lah  /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver/ojdbc.jar
-rw------- 1 root root 3.9M Feb 21  2020 /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver/ojdbc.jar
```

Keycloak from official Docker images is running under user ID `1000`, not under the `root` user. So Keycloak can't see downloaded driver and Keycloak application behaves like there is no Oracle JDBC driver present. That's a difference. Permissions on the driver file.